# How to convert word text data into html using PHP

Tags: php, html, text

I have a html text area where users can add any text. What I want is if a user copies text from his word document or rtf and put into the text area, that text should be formatted into html using html.

I have used php's nl2br function but it just creates new lines. What I want is if there are any headings, bold, bullets in word, then they should be converted into html.

Any help will be of great use.

Thanks

Comment: Good luck. Not even Microsoft can get this one right.

Comment: Any text pasted in a textarea will be plain text. You're looking for the [`contentEditable`](ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable) property. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla

Answer (score 2):

Use [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com). It has a function that do exactly what you are asking. Just to clarify, this is a client-side script. Anyway, your user will always pass through the text area (part of a form), so it can be used and works well.

Comment: This runs on the client. It's not PHP.

Comment: @Diodeus Obviously. But the question is that the user will pass through a text area (part of a form) so it can be done client-side.

Comment: sorry for late reply. the issue with the project is that there is an existing sql server database on which I don't have any control. The users generally paste data through Microsoft Word on a dotnet(C#) developed software which updates the database. In my project I have to fetch that particular data on a PHP website. By default it is not properly formatted. So I wanted it to format that through HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about posting data then use `htmlspecialchars` to avoid HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

Look at some of the PHP and Javascript-powered WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) text editors, such as tinymce. These generally can handle such things, and you can look at the source to get an idea of how it's done.